# Develop using fingerprint with android

Tags: android, security, fingerprint

i'm trying to develop an application that works with digital fingerprint. My question is... can I develop using the SDK Pass API of Samsung to enable fingerprint and get information of it. Later I want to connect via OAuth but the most important thing now is to get the fingerprint information.

Thanks